# How to make this PHP Loop working in Blade?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, laravel-blade

I have this loop written so I can easily make a 'page builder' with Advanced Custom Fields. Recently I switched to Blade, but I can't get this loop to work properly. This loop works but I cant use any blade tags in my includes. If I use php to echo fields rather than {{ the_field('field');  }} it works. But I want to use {{ the_field('field'); }} in my include. If I use the tag now, it echoes the tag itself.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
@php
    $flexible_content = '';
    if( have_rows('partials', get_queried_object_id()) ):
        while( have_rows('partials', get_queried_object_id()) ): the_row();
            $row_layouts = [
                'content-1',
            ];
            foreach( $row_layouts as &$layout ) {
                if( get_row_layout() == $layout ):
                    ob_start();
                    include( get_template_directory() . '/views/partials/'.$layout.'.blade.php' );
                    $flexible_content .= ob_get_clean();
                endif;
            }
        endwhile;
    endif;
    echo $flexible_content;
@endphp
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that your code is not working,

Inside a blade @php tag, the blade syntax is desactivated, so you have to use the php syntax.

Blade syntax is just an other way to use php, when you use `{{ $something }}` blade read it and translate it to `<?php echo $something ?>` for the server.

It is the same for the `if` and the `while` instruction, you have to use `{}` instead of `endif` and `endwhile`.